# Are these equations derivations of the other?

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

It is stated   **P**(**A|B**) = {**P**(**A** and **B**)}{**P**(**B**)}

I would like to know if this is a derived from the Bayes' theorem **P**(**A|B**) = { **P**(**A**)* **P(B|A)** }/{**P(B)** }

Comment: No, it is the definition of conditional probability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is the converse.  Bayes' Theorem may be derived from the definition of conditional probability.  $$\mathsf P(A\mid B)=\dfrac{\mathsf P(A\cap B)}{\mathsf P(B)}\qquad\text{and}\qquad\mathsf P(B\mid A)=\dfrac{\mathsf P(A\cap B)}{\mathsf P(A)}\\\text{therefore}\\~\\\mathsf P(A\mid B)=\dfrac{\mathsf P(A)\,\mathsf P(B\mid A)}{\mathsf P(B)}$$

However, the factor of $\mathsf P(A\cap B)$ cannot be deduced from Bayes' Theorem.